# How to read a dynamically growing file with Java? without clicking on save button

Tags: java

This is random file access program. If i am adding anything new in that file it is reading that much data, but the problem is it is reading after click on save button.

I want to read that new data without clicking on save button.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class ConsoleReader {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            File file = new File("C:/Users/Binayak/Desktop/file1.txt");
               try {
                   RandomAccessFile r = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rws");
                   //First time read
                   String str = null;
                   while((str = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("read"+str);
                   }
                   r.seek(r.getFilePointer());
                   startTimer(r);
               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } 
            }

        private static void startTimer(final RandomAccessFile r) {
         Timer timer = new Timer();
         timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
         String str = null;
         try {
              while((str = r.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println(str);
              } 
              r.seek(r.getFilePointer()); 
         } catch (IOException e) { 
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
          }
     }, 0, 500);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Really I need help..Please help me to slove this issue

Comment: thats beacuse your RandomAccessFile r is final in startTimer().. you cant change value of final thing..

Comment: when a variable is set as final you cannot assign a new object to it. However you can change its properties

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an instance of RandomAccessFile again. Only then will it read the remaining data. You can try with the following code :

```
public static long pointerLocation = 0L;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = "C:/Users/Binayak/Desktop/file1.txt"
        File file = new File(filename);
           try {
               RandomAccessFile r = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rws");
               //First time read
               String str = null;
               while((str = r.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("read"+str);
               }
               pointerLocation = r.getFilePointer();
               startTimer(filename);
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } 
        }

    private static void startTimer(final String filename ) {
     Timer timer = new Timer();
     timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
     File file = new File(filename);
     RandomAccessFile r = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rws");
     r.seek(pointerLocation);

     String str = null;
     try {
          while((str = r.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(str);
          } 
          pointerLocation = r.getFilePointer(); 
     } catch (IOException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
      }
 }, 0, 500);
    }
```

Comment: This wont work you are trying to change the value of final r, r=raf.

Comment: you can use raf instead of r in run()

Comment: I have edited the answer. Now only the filename will be passed and the pointerLocation will be stored globally

Comment: will point out one more issue.. each time the run() invokes then a new file object is created.. and you are not closing file instance.. then it will create a problem.. too many open connections

Comment: I have only modified the code to try to make it work. As you pointed out correctly it is always a good idea to close instances after the work is done.